# Dagger 2.10 How can I add new modules in activity

Tags: android, dagger-2

Previously I had something like this:

```
((MyApp) getApplication()).getApplicationComponent())
        .newMyActivitySubcomponent(new MyActivityModule(this))
        .inject(this);
      (...)
}
```

Now I have only:

```
AndroidInjection.inject(this);
```

How can I have different subcomponents/components for different activities?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am mistaken, the proper way to do this is by utilizing "ActivityScopes" (more information found here: http://frogermcs.github.io/dependency-injection-with-dagger-2-custom-scopes/).

If I understand this correctly, you must create a different component for each activity for which you wish to use a different module, and then add whatever module you wish to use with the activity matched to each component with said component.

Comment: Let's say that I want to use that newMyActivitySubcomponent in 2 out of 5 activities in my application. How can I do this in dagger 2.10?